# flash_timedout = "true" when user session expires in rails using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

My code for session time out is as follows:

In sessions_controller:

> prepend_before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

In user model:

> devise :timeoutable, :timeout_in => 2.minutes

application.html.erb:

> ```
> <%=content_tag :div, msg, :class =>"flash_#{key}", :id => "app_flash"%>
> ```

If my session expires, i am getting an error "Your session has expired..." from devise errors which is fine.

But i am getting extra error outside the form as "true" where i inspect it as **[:flash_timedout]**.

Please help me how to disable this **true** [:flash_timedout] ?

Answer (score 4):

That is a known issue. You must only display `:notice` and `:alert` messages or remove the `:timedout` key from the flash hash as stated in the Devise documentation.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Comment: I am not mentioning :timed_out key anywhere. I searched with the above url but could not find the correct solution for removing  the [:flash_timedout] "true".

Comment: Sorry, it is `timedout`, not `timed_out`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, its is timedout. I am not mentioning **:timedout** key anywhere. I searched with the above url but could not find the correct solution for removing the **[:flash_timedout]** **"true"**.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable `[:flash_timedout]` "true" and provide customized error.

I wrote below steps in my message partial:

```
  <% if flash[:timedout] && flash[:alert] %>
    <% flash.keep(:timedout) %>
    <% flash.keep(:alert) %>
    <div class = "alert alert-danger">
      Your session expired. Please sign in again to continue.
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <% flash.each do |name, message| %>
      <div class = "alert alert-<%= message.include?('Invalid') ? 'danger' : 'success'%>">
       <ul>
          <%= message %>
       </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```